# Word for sandbox/journal/scrapbook/testing area, related to writing

Tags: single-word-requests

I know the word exists, I can't remember what the word is, but it means "area for rough work", and is related to pen and paper notes.

I.e. "I took notes on/in my __."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest

> **scratch pad**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1** A notepad.
>
> *He also keeps on that clipboard a scratch pad where he jots down ideas for a screenplay he's developing (he wouldn't share the details) and verses for his hobby as a spoken-word poet.*

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/scratch_pad).

Comment: I think that's it! I had "sketch pad" in my head but that's for drawing

Comment: Also **scratch paper**, see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scratch%20paper).